# How do I remove my reported issue from google code bug tracking?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-code

I have accidentally added personal information during the creation of a bug ticket on google code

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

I would like to know how to delete this ticket, as I cannot see any delete or remove option.

Comment: Not sure if this question belong here or on another stack site. In case let me know I will move it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate on SO, but to answer your question, I think someone from google can make your ticket "private" so only you and google team members can see it. I don't think you have any control over it :/\

Answer (score 0):

you can flag your issue, if you dont see option login from another account and tell your friends to flag it as well and it might get deleted or nobody will pay it enough attention